# Validation in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

In my project Validation messages are not displaying, not getting any error just messages are not displaying. What is mistake?

Here is portion of code of model, view and controller:

Model:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
 public string Username { get; set; }

 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
 public string Password { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 { 
     return View();
 }
```

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label id="label">Username</label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { @class ="form-control", placeholder = "Please enter your Username", @style = "height : 45px" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})               
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
      <label id="label">Password</label>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Please enter your Password", @style = "height : 45px" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })               
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are not including '**jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js**' and/or '**jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js**'. I believe these are required to interpret the metadata added by DataAnnotations and supply the validation methods your looking for.

Refer this link for the better understanding

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

Comment: do i have to include both of them?

Comment: No anyone of them